# text color of textview inside listview row changes when scrolling

Tags: android, colors, scroll, textview

i have a listview which is generated via a custom cursoradapter

everything is working fine, except when i scroll up and down through the list, some of the textview's are changing to GREEN randomly.

heres my code which generates the listview:

```
private class AchievementAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public AchievementAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.achView1);

        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("completed")).equals("yes")) {
            tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"))+" (completed)");
            tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else {
            tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.achievements_item, parent, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

i read something about setcachecolorhint, but the method does not apply to a textview. how do i fix this so it stops changing textview colors randomly when i scroll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set textView color to normal in the `else` statement like:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.achView1);

    if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("completed")).equals("yes")) {
        tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"))+" (completed)");
        tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else {
        tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // Set your textview color as you need
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i used `Color.WHITE` and it worked, but what if their ui has a white background by default? ive tried using `int oldColor =  tv.getTextColors().getDefaultColor()` and and setting `tv.setTextColor(oldColor)` and the problem still persists.

Comment: what do you mean by 'their ui?'

Comment: well i assumed not all android devices will have the same default background color for apps...

Comment: your application will have same background on all android devices. if my answer is helpful to you please mark as an aswer to close this question